# How to get date fields and manipulate them

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to figure out how to detract days from a date, lets say I set the current date

```
set $date
```

How can I detract days from it and get the date of that period?

for example `27jul2012` detracting 5 becomes `22jul2012`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `date` to calculate the difference, e.g.

```
date -d "27jul2012 - 5 days" +%d%b%Y
```

Comment: Hi, thx for the advice, and it is possible to asdsign this to a variable? i'm trying with:  passato=date -d "27jul2012 - 90 days" +%Y%m%d   but i'm not getting the value stored in the variable

Comment: You need to assign the result of the execution rather than the command itself -- enclose the command in either backticks or `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to seconds first, subtract the number of seconds in five days and convert back:

```
date --date=@$(($(date --date='27 Jul 2012' +'%s') - $((5 * 24 * 3600)) )) +%x
```

Comment: Not so useful for GNU date, which can do this sort of thing natively, but a good approach for other `date`s which can't, e.g. for FreeBSD: `date -j -f '%s' $(($(date -j -f '%d %h %Y' '27 Jul 2012' '+%s') - $((5 * 24 * 3600)) )) +%x`

Comment: @Sorpigal: Yep. I just upvoted the Larses answer for reminding me :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the date utility to convert your date in second. see at [Bash script compare two date variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895159/bash-script-compare-two-date-variables).

and you can also perform several different kind of addition and subtraction from the current date. Have a look there : http://linuxconfig.org/addition-and-subtraction-arithmetics-with-linux-date-command

Answer (score 0):

A slightly shorter version:

```
date --date="@$(expr $(date +%s) - 432000)"
```

Where 432000 is the number of seconds in 5 days.

Comment: It certainly works, but it requires an external calculation to know how many seconds are in 5 days and an extra process to do the math. `date` already handles both issues when parsing the argument to the `-d` option.

Comment: Indeed, I wasn't aware `date` could do that. Interesting!

Comment: Daylight savings means that not every day has 86400 seconds