# How to read date from terminal and compare with current date

Tags: linux, shell, unix, date

I want to know the appropriate way of reading date from terminal and comparing with current date using shell script,

I have the below script,

```
a=`date +%Y-%m-%d`
while [ 1 ] ; do
        echo "Enter Date"
    read todate
    if [ $todate < $a ];then
        break;
    fi
    echo "todate greater than curDate" 
done
```

it is not running as expected. Please help me.

**UPDATE**

Here is my final version,

```
#! /bin/bash
DATE=$(date '+%s')
while [ 1 ] ; do
        echo "Enter Date[DD MM YYYY]:"    
    read D M Y
    THIS=$(date -d "$Y-$M-$D" '+%s')

    if (( THIS < DATE )) ; then
        break
    fi
done
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: use the **date** command as explained here:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5895607/828193

Comment: Thanks, let me check that.

Comment: `[ $todate < $a ]'` invokes the command `[` with the arguments `$todate ]` and input redirected from the file named in the variable `a`.  I suspect that is not what you intend.  Use `[ $a -lt $b ]` to compare integers.

Answer (score 4):

from [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide:](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)

7.3. Other Comparison Operators

...

string comparison

...

> ```
> <
>     is less than, in ASCII alphabetical order
>
>     if [[ "$a" < "$b" ]]
>
>     if [ "$a" \< "$b" ]
>
>     Note that the "<" needs to be escaped within a [ ] construct.
> ```

So, your

```
   if [ $todate < $a ];then
```

becomes

```
if [ $todate \< $a ];then
```

or

```
if [[ $todate < $a ]];then
```

Comment: Since not every `date` supports `%s` this is slightly more portable, with the caveat that you must always use YMD order and zero padding (i.e. `+%Y-%m-%d` as in the original questions).

Comment: Note that not all versions of `[` (nor all shells for which `[` is a builtin) will accept `<` as an operator.  `bash`, and surprisingly `dash` accept `<`.  `ksh` and `zsh` do not.

Answer (score 2):

date has `+%s` format.

```
 %s     seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC
```

you save current date in second. Then convert user input date also in second. so you could compare.

Answer (score 0):

## Here is the solution:

#### Here in this solution i am converting dates to single integer and it is obvious that greater date will always be larger integer than current date

a=`date +%Y%m%d`

while [ 1 ] ; do

echo "Enter Date"
    read todate
    echo "$todate" > temp

```
for i in 1 2 3
    do 
      y=`cut -d- -f$i temp`
      x=$x$y
    done 
if [ $x -lt $a ];then
    exit;
fi
echo "todate greater than curDate"
```

done