# Shell script: fire a command if system time is equal to given time

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am very new to shell scripting.
The script should fire a command if the given time as command line argument is equal to the system time, else it should wait(poll) for the given time.

I started with very basics, but i am stuck here only:-(

```
#!/bin/sh

now=$(date +%k%M)
cur="055" # should be given as command line arg
if ($now == $cur)
then
    echo "Fire command here"
else
    echo "poll for time"
fi
```

When i execute the script:

`./script.sh: line 5: 055: command not found`

`poll for time`

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you know [`cron`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/cron) can trigger command at given time

Comment: Are you talking about `cron jobs` ?

Comment: Check here [How to read date from terminal and compare with current date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14501734/802365).

Comment: yep, I was talking about cron jobs, just as another POV on your problem

Comment: @James Should you be specific on the very second, minute or hour? You could also use `crontab` or `at`, but to make life easier you could also wrap them with a script.

Answer (score 3):

I think the above is just a small syntax error, instead of:

```
if ($now == $cur)
```

You may want to do this:

```
if [ $now -eq $cur ]  #very basic comparison here, you may want to have a
                      #look at the bash comparisons
```

**Update**
Could you change the variable to,

```
$cur=$(date +%H%M)
```

And in case the input is not provided by you, you should remove the space in front 
of the `$now`

```
now=$(echo $now | sed 's/\s//g') #this removes the spaces in the input
```

Comment: if i use `if [ $now -eq $cur ]` , i get `./script.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'`
`poll for time` , i don't know why?

Comment: Did you put a space between the `[` and the `$now`?

Comment: I used the syntax suggested by you, it reflects the error:`./script.sh: line 5: [: missing `]'`

Comment: I mean, are you going to get from the command line the values padded by `\s` if the hour value is less than 10?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a program @ a particular time with :

```
crontab -e
```

and

```
0 14 * * * command
```

to run `command` @ 14 PM (by example)

Answer (score 0):

```
begin="`date '+%s'`"
final=... #should be converted to seconds since epoch...
sleep $((final - begin))
exec_your_command
```

Comment: Thanks, it does the job but calculating seconds since epoch is not user friendly. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described seems to be exactly what crontab is designed to handle, from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) "Cron is driven by a crontab (cron table) file, a configuration file that specifies shell commands to run periodically on a given schedule."

Here is a [quick reference](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/), it is reletively barebones, but should be enough to determine if it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

if [ $now == $cur ]